# Referencing a template from an inner class

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code

```
  template<typename VP,bool b>
  class ValueProcessor{
    template<typename Access,typename X> void processValue(X& x){}
  };


  template<typename VP>
  class ValueProcessor<VP,true>{
  public:
    template<typename Access,typename X> void processValue(X& x);
  };

  template<typename VP>  
  template<typename Access,typename X> 
  void ValueProcessor<VP,true>::processValue(X& x){
    class Updater{
      ValueProcessor<VP,false> valPro;
      X x;
    public:
      void operator()(){
        valPro.processValue<Access,X>(x);
      };
    };
  }
```

but it fails with this error

```
    source>: In member function 'void ValueProcessor<VP, true>::processValue(X&)::Updater::operator()()':
<source>:23:32: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
   23 |      valPro.processValue<Access,X>(x);
      |      

                      ^
```

How can I refer to `Access` from the inner class?

Comment: Try `valPro.template processValue<Access,X>(x);`.

Comment: that fixed it! please make this as an answer so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment the solution is to add a `.template` discrimitaor before the member function name:

`valPro.template processValue<Access,X>(x);`

This is necessary because the type of `ValueProcessor<VP,false> valPro` is a *dependent type* (i.e. it's actual type depends on the type of the template parameter VP) the c++ language requires to add the `.template` disambiguator if you want to call a template member function of `VP`. Otherwise the parser would interpret the opening `<` as less-than operator.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) for a more in-depth discussion. The template disambiguator is described at the very end of that article.